# jQuery.data and dynamically changing HTML5 custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### The problem:

jQuery objects html5 custom attributes DATA is being cached.

In my application I have a form with a field that has a changing custom data attribute, and this specific behavior is imperative for the functionally of the form.

#### What we have here:

There is an input field with some default custom attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="xxx" data-test="4">
```

#### Get the custom attribute

for `$('input').data()` the result would be `{ test="4" }`

#### change custom attribute

`$('input').attr('data-test','5')`

#### Get the custom attribute - again

for `$('input').data()` the result would **STILL** be `{ test="4" }`

#### Question

How can I always make sure to get all the REAL custom attributes, there can be more than one on an element, using the `$.data()` function? I have tried the `$.removeData()` before each fetch, but it cleans all the data completely from the element so it isn't accessible any longer.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do this: `$('input').data( 'test' , 5 )`

If you call `.attr( 'test' , 5 )` you will be setting an attribute, and you are affecting it like this `<input type='text' data-test='4' test='5' />`

As a note, you can get specific data attributes like this: `var test = $('input').data('test');`

**edit**

For removing a specific data attribute, you can do this: `jQuery.removeData( $( 'input' ) , "test" );`

Comment: note - also when using `data` to set data, you should use camel case so `data-my-attribute` should be referenced as `myAttribute'

Comment: Thats interesting, I had never considered that before. Looking back, I have only ever used one word attributes.