# Why jQuery.data() method does not update my data attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Having a html like this:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-hoo-foo="bar"></div>
```

I'm trying the following:

```
var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');      // returns 'bar'
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo', 'asdf');
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');      // returns 'asdf'
$mydiv.attr('data-hoo-foo'); // returns 'bar'
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 4):

Wheny you store data using jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method it stores the data **internally**  and **doesn't** update the [HTML5 data- attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

What it does, is that it **initializes** the value in the internal cache from the data- attribute, when you first call the .data() method.

You might get confused because of how the getter version of the .data() method works. When you call $elem.data('someAttr') it:

1. Looks up the camel case key (e.g. someAttr) in $.cache. If found, returns the value.
2. [Changes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) the camel case key into the dash separated version (e.g. some-attr) and tries it again. If found, returns the value. This value might originate from the HTML5 data- attribute, as mentioned.

examples:

```
var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');        // 'bar' - initialized from the data attribute
$mydiv.data('hooFoo');         // 'bar' - initialized from the data attribute
$mydiv.attr('data-hoo-foo');   // 'bar' - directly from the data attribute

$mydiv.data('hoo-foo', 'asdf');
$mydiv.data('hooFoo');         // 'asdf' - from the stored data by 'hoo-foo' key
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');        // 'asdf' - from the stored data by 'hoo-foo' key
$mydiv.attr('data-hoo-foo');   // 'bar' - the data attribute remains unchanged

$mydiv.data('hooFoo', 'blah');
$mydiv.data('hooFoo');         // 'blah' - key 'hooFoo' exists
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');        // 'asdf' - key 'hoo-foo' exists
$mydiv.attr('data-hoo-foo');   // 'bar' - still unchanged

$mydiv.data('hoo-foo', 'ugh'); // this will override the 'hooFoo' key too
$mydiv.data('hooFoo');         // 'ugh'
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');        // 'ugh'
$mydiv.attr('data-hoo-foo');   // 'bar' - still unchanged

$mydiv.removeData('hoo-foo');  // removes both 'hooFoo' and 'hoo-foo' keys
$mydiv.data('hooFoo');         // 'bar' - key 'hooFoo' adn 'hoo-foo' undefined
                               // initializing as 'hoo-foo' from data- attribute
$mydiv.data('hoo-foo');        // 'bar' - key 'hoo-foo' exists
$mydiv.attr('data-hoo-foo');   // 'bar' - still unchanged
```

I had kinda hard time figuring this out and didn't have luck finding the complete answer. That's why I'm posting it here. Please correct me if anything isn't precise. I tried to figure out the exact behavior from [the code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js), but it's a heck lotta code, so tried it rather empirically ;)

For reference some other questions touching this issue:

- [Assigning individual keys of object stored in jQuery.data()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837471/assigning-individual-keys-of-object-stored-in-jquery-data)
- [jQuery.data and dynamically changing HTML5 custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414343/jquery-data-and-dynamically-changing-html5-custom-attributes)

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted even sounds like a duplicate but still can be useful for some other searching reason why